# Cannot restore a database with a .bak file due to another SQL server version

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have installed SQL server 2008 R2 and i try to restore a database a colleague sent me in a .bak file.

Unfortunately, i cannot restore the database since the database was saved on a server from version 10.50.1600 and my SQL server version seems to be 10.00.1600.

I tried to upgrade my SQL server with SP1 and SP2 packs but it didn't change anything.

Otherwise, i noticed by clicking on the server property that the line "product" displays Microsoft SQL server Express edition even though i have installed SQL server 2008 R2. That's at least what is displayed when i fire it...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, restoring just with different service packs. Sounds like your install has a problem if your license is also telling you you have express version.

Comment: 10.50 **is** SQL Server **2008 R2**, so if you've installed that version, you should be able to restore to it. Maybe it's a separate, named instance on your machine? It seems you're connecting to a **2008** (v10.00) version by default - you won't be able to restore to that version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** (SQL Server 2008 R2 - 10.50.1600) of SQL Server down to an **older version** (2008 - v10.00.1600) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.

Comment: Do you think it will work if i install a newer version of SQL server ( 2012)

Comment: Yes - you can always go upwards - to newer versions - but you can never go back. However: if you install SQL Server 2012 and restore that database onto the 2012 server, you won't be able to give it back to whoever gave it to you on 2008 R2 ....

Comment: @marc_s re: your 2nd point, can you recommend a third-party tool that will automate what Tasks > Generate does? Thanks!

Comment: @GaryChapman: you could have a look at [Red-Gate SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/) - it can package an entire database (structure and data) into an `.exe`, but also generates a `.sql` script for you, if that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

[Understand, what the version numbers mean.](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.de/) You need to be on R2 which is not just a patch or service-pack.

Comment: Thanks , do you know where i can find the correct version i need ?

Comment: You need SQL Server 2008 R2 according to the table because that is the server version the backup was taken with.